# OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied:

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to install a library package to python but I get the following error:

```
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/PackageName'
```

I've looked online and tried the following, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
chown -R $USER /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pync
```

and also:

```
chown -R $USER /Library/Python/2.7
```

Comment: use `sudo` in your command

Comment: I tried that also...I still get the error.

Comment: Can you post how you did this command?

Comment: Or may be you don't have permission to install?..I suppose it's a linux distro..right?

Comment: How I did the command is in the question details. For sudo, I just added sudo in front of it.

Comment: You didn't show us how you did the `install` command...

Comment: Oh...-> pip install packageName. it looks like it installs then I get the error and the package is not installed

Comment: And What package are you trying to install?

Comment: twitter            ..............

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with your first attempt is that you won't have created pync for the chmod to work yet.

```
chown: /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pync: No such file or directory
```

The problem with your second attempt is that $vdixon is a variable expansion -- it will evaluate to the empty string in most cases and result in help being printed on a mac.

```
usage: chown [-fhv] [-R [-H | -L | -P]] owner[:group] file ...
       chown [-fhv] [-R [-H | -L | -P]] :group file ...
```

You don't actually show what went wrong in your question so it's hard to say but if it matches the above, we're on the right track.

All that being said, you don't want to change ownership of your system Python.  Instead, you might want to have the root user install the module.  I'll follow up with a way that you can avoid even that but first, let's solve the problem at hand.

To solve your particular issue try whichever one most closely matches what you were doing originally:

```
sudo python setup.py install
```

or

```
sudo pip install <package name>
```

or

```
sudo easy_install <package name>
```

Now, these will have installed the package and you can stop reading.

... but let's say you want to avoid having to pollute your system Python installation with modules that may not be compatible with others.  For this, the Python community uses virtualenv.  Virtualenv still generally is installed in the system Python site-packages but that's considered the last thing you'll ever have to.  Here's how you might do what you're trying to do with virtualenv instead:

```
sudo pip install virtualenv
virtualenv my_app_virtualenv
. my_app_virtualenv/bin/activate
pip install <package name>
# (or python setup.py install or easy_install <package name>)
```

Whenever you want to use the dependency you've installed in the virtualenv again, you'll run:

```
. my_app_virtualenv/bin/activate
```

There are further improvements to be made to the process with virtualenvwrapper if this is a common thing you're doing.

Read more at http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/

Comment: Okay. I am confused. I did sudo pip install <package name> and it installed without the error. I did that before (without sudo I guess), what has changed? ...Thank you!

Comment: When you run it with sudo, it runs as root.The two following commands that you probably did run as sudo were invalid commands so they wouldn't run correctly as any user.